# Find matching words in a database and a long string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a large database of cities and towns (around 300 000) and I am trying -using python- to check if a given string contains one of these cities.

What is the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: With regex. Any other question?

Comment: You mean city by city?

Comment: Join everything with `|`.

Comment: How large the set of city names is? Does it fit into memory?

Comment: This is the problem, it is not possible to load everything into memory.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How many cities are there? What is the total sum of lengths of city name strings? (or average length of a city name)

Comment: Does it require Python database programming?

Comment: @Radek around 300.000

Comment: Create a hash of the cities and town in a hash table. Now your string split it by " " and look if the individual words matches any city name when searching in the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Though not the most optimal way to do it, but one way could be to split your long string into list of words. Then for each word query the database using `LIKE` regex.
Eg: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE city LIKE '%word%'`